# Using tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory() in SageMaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, tf.keras

Im using the below method as the entry point to train a model. Does anyone know how to feed data from AWS S3 bucket into the 'img_dir' variable? In SageMaker, it appears 'img_dir' is looking locally, which means '/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/....'

```
tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    img_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(...))
```

The path to the S3 image directories:

```
s3://data-ma5852/image_data/
```

The path above, directly, does not work, needs be parsed and put in memory, and then accessed (i think).

Obviously I can get it to work in SageMaker (locally), however, would like to access the data from S3 not SageMaker.

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your use case:

1. If you're training on a SageMaker notebook then you can copy the data from S3 to the SageMaker notebook filesystem, and access locally.
2. If you're working with a very large dataset, you can switch from a notebook to running a [training job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html), which spins a new instance, and automatically reads/streams the data from S3.